# Register generic type in DbContext EF4 CTP5

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef4-code-only

in EF4 CTP4 we had RegisterSet function to generically register entity in ModelBuilder. We used Configurations.Add() to register the mapping for entities. How to achieve this EF4 CTP 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to problem. They have exposed ModelBuilder.Entity().{Configuration} like Property/IsRequired and all for simple types. For complex entities there are functions like ComplexTypes.